# how to construct object of the same type that `tf.one_hot` returns?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I have a function `input_preprocess` that I am using in the data pipeline:

```
def input_preprocess(image, label):
    if label == 1:
        return tf.zeros(NUM_CLASSES)
    else:
        label = tf.one_hot(label, NUM_CLASSES)
    return image, label
```

The problem is that whatever `tf.one_hot` returns is a `sequence` but what `tf.zeros` returns is not.

I get the following error:

```
 The two structures don't have the same nested structure.
    
    First structure: type=Tensor str=Tensor("cond/zeros_like:0", shape=(28,), dtype=float32)
    
    Second structure: type=tuple str=(<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'cond/one_hot:0' shape=(28,) dtype=float32>)
    
    More specifically: Substructure "type=tuple str=(<tf.Tensor 'args_0:0' shape=(224, 224, 3) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'cond/one_hot:0' shape=(28,) dtype=float32>)" is a sequence, while substructure "type=Tensor str=Tensor("cond/zeros_like:0", shape=(28,), dtype=float32)" is not
    Entire first structure:
    .
    Entire second structure:
    (., .)
```

How can I manually construct something that could stand in for what `tf.one_hot` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.one_hot` returns an `EagerTensor` just like `tf.zeros`:

```
a = tf.one_hot(1,2)
print(type(a))
b = tf.zeros(2)
print(type(b))
# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
# tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
```

I think your issue is that your *function* `input_preprocess` returns a *single value* if `label == 1` (first return) and a *tuple* otherwise (second return).

Comment: thank you very much @SuperCiocia, this was it!!! no clue how I missed that... appreciate your help!